# Migrate PostgreSQL local db to Heroku on Windows 7

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Noob to Heroku and Postgres, and using Windows 7 and git bash to try to port my local Django postgres 9.4 database to Heroku. 
At the moment I'm stuck with a server 500 error on my heroku app.
But the Django site and database work fine on my local environment (ie. my laptop).

I've tried multiple permutations of what appear to be the main methods to to migrate the local database, such as the following:

### 1. Reset followed by pg:push

```
$ heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK
$ PGUSER=MyUsername PGPASSWORD=MyPassword heroku pg:push localdb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK -a MyAppname
```

Errors:

> pg_dump: blah blah blah
>
> :
>
> pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in header
>
> pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid
>   argument
>
> And $ heroku pg:info showed 0 tables

### 2. Dump db to SQL and try to push that

```
$ pg_dump -U MyUsername -d localdb --no-owner --no-acl -f backup.sql
$ heroku pg:psql --app MyAppname < backup.sql
```

(btw, the backup.sql file was populated and looked fine)

Errors:

> Nothing happened, just a new line in bash.

And $ heroku pg:info showed 0 tables

### 3. Dump db, copy to Dropbox and try to restore that

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > database.dump
$ heroku pg:backups restore 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/bunch_of_chars/database.dump?dl=0' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL -a MyAppname --confirm MyAppname
```

(I, of course, copied database.dump to Dropbox)

Errors:

> Bash just hangs, showing:
>
> r004 --restore--> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK
>
> <-[0KRunning... 0.00B

After several hours I cancel out of it.

And $ heroku pg:info showed 0 tables

### 4. Connect pgAdmin to Heroku

I use pg:config to get the details of my Heroku database.
I add ssl, and enter the heroku 'dbname' in database restriction
I then try to connect.

Errors:

> pgAdmin just hangs, so a couple hours later I kill the process.

All advice I've seen has been to try pushing, or restoring the database. 
But this doesn't seem to be working for my configuration.

Any other advice/solutions please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "blah blah" isn't very useful. Please include full, exact errors, arguments, etc. Wild guess: you used `pg_dump` without `-Fc` then tried to feed the output to `pg_restore`. (I don't use Heroku so I can't really comment on the Heroku-specific bits).

Comment: Ah no, I did use -Fc, as in:

PGPASSWORD=MyPassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U Myusername crosstech > database.dump

Comment: And the blah blah was abbreviation for about 5,000 characters, which seemed too long for the post, and in which there didn't seem any problems (until the end bit).  It was something like this:


pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
.........
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument

Comment: aah, on Windows there are possible issues with stdio redirection not being 8-bit clean. Try using `pg_dump -f database.dump ....` . I'm hoping to have the time to investigate this and see if I can patch `pg_dump` to detect that and error out.

Comment: this worked for me "pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d rails_db_development > mydb.dump"

Answer (score 1):

I changed the link of Dropbox a little bit and then it works. 
What I changed is `dl=0` into `dl=1`, so that heroku could download from Dropbox instead of open the downloading page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11708886)

Comment: Sounds silly. Good answers are rejected because of so called reputation

Comment: The problem wasn't that the dropbox link wasn't working, rather that importing a dump on heroku wasn't working. So you did not actually answer the question. It is not a matter of reputation, rather quality of answer. I believe this should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @elssar Importing a dump on heroku wasn't working is caused by the wrong dropbox link. Heroku should download the dump directly from the link provided.

Comment: the OP tried 4 different ways to import the dump, and none of them worked. So its unlikely that fixing the link will help.

Comment: I posted it because I tried it. And this "4 different ways" has nothing to do with this "unlikely" in logic. If you wish to show that I'm wrong, you'd better provide more persuasive arguments next time. Thanks.